# Ruby on Rails datetime_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if there was a way to covert the 24 hour clock of a datetime_select to a 12 hour clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's [no predefined helper to do this particular job automatically](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/122263). You've to [extend and write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143848/rails-3-datetime-select-with-am-pm-options) your own helper for this functionality.

Also, [this is a very old plugin](http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/810-12-hour-time-select), I am not sure this works or is still maintained, for similar thing.

I suggest you to go ahead and write your own helper to do the job as suggested in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143848/rails-3-datetime-select-with-am-pm-options) like this:

```
def am_pm_hour_select(field_name)
select_tag(field_name,options_for_select([
    ["1 AM", "01"],["2 AM", "02"],["3 AM", "03"],["4 AM", "04"],["5 AM", "05"],["6 AM", "06"],
    ["7 AM", "07"],["8 AM", "08"],["9 AM", "09"],["10 AM", "10"],["11 AM", "11"],["Noon", "12"],
    ["1 PM", "13"],["2 PM", "14"],["3 PM", "15"],["4 PM", "16"],["5 PM", "17"],["6 PM", "18"],
    ["7 PM", "19"],["8 PM", "20"],["9 PM", "21"],["10 PM", "22"],["11 PM", "23"],["Midnight", "0"]]))
end
```

And then in the view:

```
<%= am_pm_hour_select "eventtime[start(4i)]" %>
```

Answer (score 13):

Rails 3.1 has the am/pm option built in:

```
<%= f.datetime_select :starttime, :ampm => true, :start_year => 2011, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
```

Comment: This needs to be made more apparent in the docs. I couldn't find this absolutely anywhere except here. Great answer.